# cannot delete an old project from SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

I have some old project (from 2011) in my SonarQube v. 5.1.
It was probably migrated/upgraded from an old Sonar install. I see it in the Projects list.

I want to delete it, but when I open the project page, there is no "Settings" menu like there is for other projects.

I'm using an account that belongs to "sonar-administrators" group.

I checked "Project Permissions" page and I don't see this project there.

also checked "Bulk deletion" page - the project is not shown there either.

the project name has some unusual symbols in it:

```
BlahBlah Server ${BRANCH}
```

maybe they are breaking some DB queries...

if I login as "admin" rather than a regular user with "sonar-administrators" group assignment, I see "Settings" menu for this project, but there is no "delete" item in it (only "General Settings", "Manual Measures" and "Update key". nothing else changes between admin and admin-group users: still can't see this project in "bulk deletion" or "project permissions" even as "admin".

so... how do I delete this ghost project? is there some safe DB query I can execute?

Comment: Have you checked the Ghosts page?

Comment: yes, I checked "ghosts" tab in "Bulk Deletion" page. not shown there.

Comment: @Alex did you find any solution for this?

Comment: no, I didn't have a change to explore their db structure and find a solution.